# Simple Universal Apps MVVM example not working for the Button Click

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, binding, win-universal-app

The text binds fine though. This is as simple as it gets. Please tell me if you see anything missing. Right now when I click the button SHOWMESSAGE is not called. I followed this example and the only different is it is WPF and sets the VM in XAML instead of code. See anything that could be missing ?

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/126249/MVVM-Pattern-in-WPF-A-Simple-Tutorial-for-Absolute

XAML

```
    <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Get Quote Questions" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextBlockStyle}" />
            <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.City}" PlaceholderText="City " />
            <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.State}" PlaceholderText="State Code " />
            <TextBox Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.ZipCode}" PlaceholderText="Zip Code " />
            <Button Content="Get Quote Questions" Command="{Binding ViewModel.GetQuoteQuestionsCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />
        </StackPanel>
```

Code Behind:

```
      public GetQuoteQuestionsVm ViewModel { get; private set; }

    public GetQuoteQuestions()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

        var vm = new GetQuoteQuestionsVm();
        this.ViewModel = vm;
    }
```

ViewModel:

```
  public class GetQuoteQuestionsVm : NotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string city;
    public string City
    {
        get { return city; }
        set { Set(ref city, value); }

    }

    private ICommand getQuoteQuestionsCommand;
    public ICommand GetQuoteQuestionsCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return getQuoteQuestionsCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            getQuoteQuestionsCommand = value;
        }
    }

    public GetQuoteQuestionsVm()
    {
        City = "Woodbridge";
        GetQuoteQuestionsCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(ShowMessage));
    }

    public async void ShowMessage(object obj)
    {
        var dialog = new MessageDialog("Your message here");
        await dialog.ShowAsync();
    }
}
```

RelayCommand:

```
    public class RelayCommand : ICommand
{
    private Action<object> _action;

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> action)
    {
        _action = action;
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        if (parameter != null)
        {
            _action(parameter);
        }
        else
        {
            _action("Hello World");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple suggestions:

1 ) 
Instead of this:

Command="{Binding ViewModel.GetQuoteQuestionsCommand, Mode=OneWay}" />

try:
Command="{Binding ViewModel.GetQuoteQuestionsCommand}" />

2) 
Don't "roll your own" RelayCommand. Use an MVVM library such as MvvmLight and use the RelayCommand provided there.

Comment: I was not using MvvmLight for the sake of learning and I am not clear on what it provides outside of rolling my own .. Also as I recall I tried to use it in a portable library and I think it has issues with ASP.NET 5.0 .. I guess there wasn't a version for that.

Comment: I only suggested it because it would make less code for you to troubleshoot.

Comment: Why do 'Mode=OneWay'??? one way means that its only read it and it doesnt send the command, Am I right?

Comment: I tried it earlier one way and twoway .. A lot of th eMS demos they are rolling their on MVVM so that's why I am wondering how useful using MVVMlight is.. I need to study up on that.. But I doing the code myself so I know what is going on